# The dual space of a nonempty normed linear space is non empty

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Is the statement true? The dual space of a nonempty normed linear space is non 
empty?

I am not able to prove or disprove, could anyone give me just hints?

I know that it will be a norm linear space too.

Comment: The Hahn-Banach theorem supplies us with linear functionals.

Comment: no vector space is empty! The zero vector is always there.

Comment: @RagibZaman Thank you...

Comment: @IttayWeiss Correct.